# Ldap ux with c++ on HPUX

Tags: c++, ldap

I have a c++ code which i am integrating with LDAP-UX for hp, so far i have manage to get simple poc running. However for production use i must be able to configure network related things like timeouts,etc and  i seemed to be in the blind on this matter. Here is a small piece of the code , at first glance i don't see any way of setting the timeout or any other options

```
LDAP *ld = ldap_init(host.c_str(), port) ; 

    if( ld == NULL)
    {
        //std::cerr << "Error in initializing LDAP against server " << host << ":" << port << std::endl;
        //throw verify_exception("Error ... see std::cerr.");
        return as::ldap::ERROR_LDAP_INIT;
    }
```

Is there any reference i can use ?